# How to combine two arrays with JOLT Transformation

Tags: json, jolt

i'm not very familiar with jolt transformation and i'm looking for help.

The input JSON is as follows:

```json
{
  "2021-03-01": {
    "hours": 0
  },
  "2021-03-02": {
    "hours": 0
  },
  "2021-03-03": {
    "hours": 6.31
  },
  "2021-03-04": {
    "hours": 6.49
  },
  "2021-03-05": {
    "hours": 0
  }
}
```

The output needed is as follows:

```json
[
  {
    "day": "2021-03-01",
    "hours": 0
  },
  {
    "day": "2021-03-02",
    "hours": 0
  },
  {
    "day": "2021-03-03",
    "hours": 6.31
  },
  {
    "day": "2021-03-04",
    "hours": 6.49
  },
  {
    "day": "2021-03-05",
    "hours": 0
  }
]
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "hours": "obj.hours",
        "$": "obj.day"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "day": {
          "*": "[&].day"
        },
        "hours": {
          "*": "[&].hours"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: understood your approach Barbaros,  your's is a more optimized and clean solution than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach might be

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "&.day",
        "*": "&1.&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where non-existing key(`day`) determined within the first step, and then the respective keys of the objects are removed within the second one. Eg. no need to repeat the key names, rather you can use symbolic substitutions.

**or** even a direct option with *just one* **shift** transformation might be given as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "[#2].day",
        "*": "[#2].&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```